# rpmbuild is building my target directory in /usr/local not where I specified

Tags: linux, rpm, prefix, rpmbuild

My rpmbuild is supposed to happen in `/include`, `/lib`, and `/share`, I have specified this in the spec file. But when in the BUILDROOT directory, it is creating in `/usr/local/include`, `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/local/share` instead. And then is throwing an error (obviously) because I am looking for the files in the previous location.

Why would this happen? Nowhere am I specifying /usr/local, then why does it take this location?

This is my `.spec` file:-

```
%define        __spec_install_post %{nil}
%define          debug_package %{nil}
%define        __os_install_post %{_dbpath}/brp-compress


Summary: test
Name: TEST
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
License: MYORG
Group: Development/Tools
SOURCE0 : %{name}.tar.gz
%define pbs_prefix /opt/dir1/TEST

BuildRoot: %{_topdir}/%{name}

%description
%{summary}

%prep
%setup -q

%build
./configure --with-prefix=/opt/dir1/TEST --with-drms-dir=/opt/dir1

%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir -p  %{buildroot}

%make_install

%clean 
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%files  
/opt/dir1/TEST/include/*
/opt/dir1/TEST/lib/*
/opt/dir1/TEST/share/*
```

My `~/.rpmmacros` file is:-

```
%_topdir   %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild
%_tmppath  %{_topdir}/tmp
```

I want to build so that my `TEST-1.0-1x86_64/` has `/include`, `/lib` and `/share` not `/usr/local/..`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--prefix` option sets your path. Not `--with-prefix`.